# Where can I find XrmServicesContext Class?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I found this snippet that provides a creation of a new entity called `annotation`.
I can't find the class  `XrmServicesContext` declared into the `using` directive. 
has anybody knows what the hell is this?

```cs
private static void AddNoteToContact(IOrganizationService service, Guid id)
{
    Entity annotation = new Entity();
    annotation.LogicalName = "annotation";
    using (var crm = new XrmServicesContext(service))
    {
        var contact = crm.ContactSet.Where(c => c.ContactId == id).First();

        Debug.Write(contact.FirstName);

        annotation["createdby"] = new EntityReference("systemuser", new Guid("2a213502-db00-e111-b263-001ec928e97f"));
        annotation["objectid"] = contact.ToEntityReference();
        annotation["subject"] = "Creato con il plu-in";
        annotation["notetext"] = "Questa note è stata creata con l'esempio del plug-in";
        annotation["ObjectTypeCode"] = contact.LogicalName;
        try
        {
            Guid annotationId = service.Create(annotation);

            crm.AddObject(annotation);
            crm.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }

        //    var note = new Annotation{

        //Subject ="Creato con il plu-in",

        //NoteText ="Questa note è stata creata con l'esempio del plug-in",

        //ObjectId = contact.ToEntityReference(),

        //ObjectTypeCode = contact.LogicalName

    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First you have to generate the early bound entity classes. [Check this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695790.aspx). Then, insert using statement in your code.

In your example you are using combination of early and late binding. I suggest you to choose one of them. In case of early binding, after generating early binding classes you can modify your code like:

```
Annotation annotation = new Annotation();
      using (var crm = new XrmServiceContext(service))
      {
        annotation.ObjectId = contact.ToEntityReference();
        annotation.Subject = "Creato con il plu-in";
        annotation.NoteText = "Questa note e stata creata con l'esempio del plug-in";
        annotation.ObjectTypeCode = Contact.LogicalName;

        crm.AddObject(annotation);
        crm.SaveChanges();
      }
```

You have one error here, *annotation.CreatedBy* field is read only and you can't set value to this from code.

If you're gonna use late binding, *XrmServiceContext* is not necessary. You can get Contact from CRM using QueryExpression. Find [examples here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328300.aspx). And for annotation create use:

```
Guid annotationId = service.Create(annotation);
```

Answer (score 0):

In SDK/bin/CrmSvcUtil.exe, This tool is used to generate early bound entity classes
from command prompt, run CrmSvcUtil.exe with parameters i.e.

If your sdk bin location is "D:\Data\sdk2013\SDK\Bin\CrmSvcUtil.exe" then your command will like this,
**cmd:**

```
D:\Data\sdk 2013\SDK\Bin>CrmSvcUtil.exe  /out:Xrm\Xrm.cs /url:[OrganizationServiceUrl]  /username:[yourusername] /password:[yourpass] /namespace:Xrm /serviceContextName:XrmServiceContext
```

**[OrganizationServiceUrl]:** is your organization service url, u can find it from setting/customization/Developer rosources/Organization service e.g

https://msdtraders.api.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc
**[yourusername]:** your user name
**[yourpass]:** your password

This will generate and Entity classes in file with name Xrm.cs in bin/Xrm/Xrm.cs. Create folder Xrm in bin if it not exist, or edit parameters in cmd [out:Xrm\Xrm.cs].
Add Xrm.cs in your project

Add using statement in your code where you use `XrmServicesContext`.
like `using Xrm;`

Now you can use/access `XrmServicesContext` and all Entities ...... enjoy.